# Run Initialization Code when a Script is Loaded

Tags: godot, gdscript, static-initializer

I have a GDScript file, and I would like to be able to run a block of code whenever the script is *loaded*. I know `_init` will run whenever an instance is constructed and `_ready` will run when it's added to the scene tree. I want to run code before either of those events happens; when the `preload` or `load` that brings it into memory first happens.

In Java, this would be a [static initializer block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), like so

```
public class Example {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> example = new ArrayList<Integer>;
    static {
        // Pretend this is a complicated algorithm to compute the example array ...
        example.add(1);
        example.add(2);
        example.add(3);
    }
}
```

I want to do the same thing with a GDScript file in Godot, where some top-level constant or other configuration data is calculated when the script is first loaded, something like (I realize this is *not* valid GDScript)

```
extends Node
class_name Example

const EXAMPLE = []

static:
    EXAMPLE.push_back(1)
    EXAMPLE.push_back(2)
    EXAMPLE.push_back(3)
```

Is there some way to get a feature like this or even to approximate it?

**Background Information:** The reason I care (aside from a general academic interest in problems like these) is that I'm working on a scripting language that uses GDScript as a compile target, and in my language there are certain initialization and registration procedures that need to happen to keep my language's runtime happy, and this needs to happen whenever a new script from my language is loaded.

In reality the thing I want to do is basically going to be

```
static:
    MyLanguageRuntime.register_class_file(this_file, ...)
```

where `MyLanguageRuntime` is a singleton node that exists at the top of the scene tree to keep everything running smoothly.

Comment: you tried to use "Autoloads" ?

Comment: Autoloads run at the start of the entire game. It's viable, I suppose, but it would subvert Godot's nice scene loading mechanics. I really want to run something when the particular file resource is loaded, not when the whole program is started up.

Comment: Maybe you could try to implement custom `ResourceFormatLoader` for your files and call a custom "static" function yourself. I didn't try to use that though. https://docs.godotengine.org/uk/stable/classes/class_resourceformatloader.html